# Disable arquillian cleanup

Tags: java, testing, jboss-arquillian

I Have a Bean that creates some default user in DB. 
In an Arquillian test I need to make test cases with @UsingDataSet.
One of tests should check if Users created by this bean exist but the created users are dropped after tests.

How can I disable Cleanup on Arquillian tests?
I tried `@Cleanup(phase = TestExecutionPhase.NONE)` but with no effects.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution, in every test I used:

```
@Cleanup(phase = TestExecutionPhase.AFTER, strategy = CleanupStrategy.USED_ROWS_ONLY)
```

It only cleanup users created by @UsingDataSet and left users created by Bean untouched.

Comment: That might be a bug. Can you open an issue on GitHub? I will take a closer look.